# UXM The resource cannot be found error when clicked on Update Preview button

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, session-preview

I'm using the "User Interface Update for Tridion 2011 SP1".

I have two applications in two different languages. In IIS, one Application is added (as Add Application and has seperate application pool and bin folder) inside the other.

Tridion UI works for main application but for the other application, which has been added inside the other application, Update Preview button is not working and throws the below error

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) 
could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /en/default.aspx
```

Although I am able to do rest of the functions of Tridion UI.

I have also followed the steps mentioned here
[Unable to preview the page. There is no publication target defined for this SiteEdit enabled website?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/unable-to-preview-the-page-there-is-no-publication-target-defined-for-this-site)

Can someone please suggest cause of the issue?

Comment: Maybe same issue resolved here by @RamG: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/4610/130