# SDL Tridion UI 2012 the resource cannot be found 404 error when clicked on finish editing button

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, experience-manager

I'm trying to complete the installation of the "User Interface Update for Tridion 2011 SP1".

Tridion UI does not work, the “Finish Editing” button is not working and throws the below error:
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /es/dglb_ui_a.aspx

Although I am able to do rest of the functions of Tridion UI. It seems like Ambient module is not properly working.

Core log for the Website application “es” (IIS application with its own application pool) does not produce neither warnings nor errors.
Core log for the Web application that contains the Content Delivery session preview Web service (IIS application with its own application pool) does not produce neither warnings nor errors.
Also, no errors neither warnings in Content Manager side (even in server event logs: “Tridion”, “Tridion Content Manager”, “Application”).
All in debug mode.

Although no errors appear in any log, when iframe shows 404 error, in the iframe source code the following is displayed:

```
[HttpException]: The file &#39;/dglb_ui_a_34a32b04-8855-4473-8242-4f6b4ccf1de4.aspx&#39; does not exist.
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
[HttpException]: Error executing child request for /dglb_ui_a_34a32b04-8855-4473-8242-4f6b4ccf1de4.aspx.
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule.OnBeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

From “http://[myhost]/es/dglb_ui_a.aspx” the right parameter for calling Transfer method should be “dglb_ui_a_34a32b04-8855-4473-8242-4f6b4ccf1de4.aspx” instead of “/dglb_ui_a_34a32b04-8855-4473-8242-4f6b4ccf1de4.aspx”.

Maybe CD is not able to properly map the publication?

***Edit 1***: Is there a way to enable http module logging?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is a path+publication mapping issue, then you should be able to fix it by editing cd_dynamic_conf.xml and configure hostnames and paths correctly in it.

Comment: I edited cd_dynamic_conf for the website application "es" with several configurations: 
<Host Domain="localhost" Port="91" Protocol="http" Path=""/>

Comment: Shouldn't it be Path="es" ?

Comment: Unfortunately same error (404). I had tried differents values for path attribute ("es", "/es", "/es/",...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to check the hotfix `CD_2011.1.1.81686`. I remember the same/similar issue when there is a virtual application on IIS with UI 2012.

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx (requires login)

Comment: Maybe same issue?: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1758/130